# Gradient calculation with python

Tags: python, numpy, gradient

I would like to know how does `numpy.gradient` work.
I used gradient to try to calculate *group velocity* (group velocity of a wave packet is the derivative of frequencies respect to wavenumbers, not a group of velocities).  I fed a 3 column array to it, the first 2 colums are x and y coords, the third column is the frequency of that point (x,y). I need to calculate gradient and I did expect a 2d vector, being gradient definition

```
df/dx*i+df/dy*j+df/dz*k
```

and my function only a function of x and y i did expect something like

```
df/dx*i+df/dy*j
```

But i got 2 arrays with 3 colums each, i.e. 2 3d vectors; at first i thought that the sum of the two would give me the vector i were searchin for but the z component doesn't vanish. I hope i've been sufficiently clear in my explanation. I would like to know how `numpy.gradient` works and if it's the right choice for my problem. Otherwise i would like to know if there's any other python function i can use.

What i mean is: I want to calculate gradient of an array of values:

```
data=[[x1,x2,x3]...[x1,x2,x3]]
```

where x1,x2 are point coordinates on an uniform grid (my points on the brillouin zone) and x3 is the value of frequency for that point. I give in input also steps for derivation for the 2 directions:

```
stepx=abs(max(unique(data[:,0])-min(unique(data[:,0]))/(len(unique(data[:,0]))-1)
```

the same for y direction.
I didn't build my data on a grid, i already have a grid and this is why kind examples given here in answers do not help me.
A more fitting example should have a grid of points and values like the one i have:

```
data=[]
for i in range(10):
  for j in range(10):
    data.append([i,j,i**2+j**2])

data=array(data,dtype=float)

gx,gy=gradient(data)
```

another thing i can add is that my grid is not a square one but has the shape of a polygon being the brillouin zone of a 2d crystal.

I've understood that `numpy.gradient` works properly only on a square grid of values, not what i'm searchin for. Even if i make my data as a grid that would have lots of zeroes outside of the polygon of my original data, that would add really high vectors to my gradient affecting (negatively) the precision of calculation. This module seems to me more a toy than a tool, it has severe limitations imho. There is anything more powerful in python or i'd better start writing from scratch something else maybe switchin to fortran?

Comment: Soooo what's the question?  What module you should use? Is something going wrong?

Comment: Question is what do gradient do? Why gives me 2 3d vectors instead of 1 2d vector? Do gradient actually compute really a gradient? By its output i cannot say. Doesn't look exact to me.

Comment: I thought it was clear, 3rd component of my input is the scalar field, each value on 3rd component is the value of my function for each (x,y) point.

Comment: the problem is that you are giving gradient the wrong input.  It doesn't care about `x1,x2` or in the last example `i,j`.  It just wants a matrix of `i**2+j**2` values.  It's implicit that your matrix of `i**2+j**2` values correspond to the `xy` plane, and the optional scalar arguments of `gradient` account for step size assumptions, i.e. if your `x` points are not `1` away from eachother, and the same for your `y` points.  I'm going out of town today but I'll update my answer when I get back tonight.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to give `gradient` a matrix that describes your angular frequency values for your `(x,y)` points.  e.g.

```
def f(x,y):
    return np.sin((x + y))
x = y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.05)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zs = np.array([f(x,y) for x,y in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)

gx,gy = np.gradient(Z,0.05,0.05)
```

You can see that plotting Z as a surface gives:

[image: sinxpy]

Here is how to interpret your gradient:

`gx` is a matrix that gives the change `dz/dx` at all points. e.g. gx[0][0] is `dz/dx` at `(x0,y0`).  Visualizing `gx` helps in understanding:

[image: gx]

Since my data was generated from `f(x,y) = sin(x+y)` gy looks the same.

Here is a more obvious example using `f(x,y) = sin(x)`...

**f(x,y)**
[image]

**and the gradients**

[image: g2]

[image: g1]

**update** Let's take a look at the xy pairs.

This is the code I used:

```
def f(x,y):
    return np.sin(x)
x = y = np.arange(-3,3,.05)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zs = np.array([f(x,y) for x,y in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
xy_pairs = np.array([str(x)+','+str(y) for x,y in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)
xy_pairs = xy_pairs.reshape(X.shape)

gy,gx = np.gradient(Z,.05,.05)
```

Now we can look and see exactly what is happening.  Say we wanted to know what point was associated with the value at`Z[20][30]`?  Then...

```
>>> Z[20][30]
-0.99749498660405478
```

And the point is

```
>>> xy_pairs[20][30]
'-1.5,-2.0'
```

Is that right?  Let's check.

```
>>> np.sin(-1.5)
-0.99749498660405445
```

Yes.

And what are our gradient components at that point?

```
>>> gy[20][30]
0.0
>>> gx[20][30]
0.070707731517679617
```

Do those check out?

`dz/dy always 0` check.
`dz/dx = cos(x)` and...

```
>>> np.cos(-1.5)
0.070737201667702906
```

Looks good.

You'll notice they aren't exactly correct, that is because my Z data isn't continuous, there is a step size of `0.05` and `gradient` can only approximate the rate of change.

Comment: Grid is already in the file i give to numpy.gradient. I cannot calculate the function as you did because i don't know the equation. I got those values from an ab initio calculation. And again: i don't know why should i have 2 3d vectors when for a 2 variables function gradient is a 2d vector...

Comment: My function was part of the contrived example, a means to generate Z data.  You say in your question you have `x,y,z` data already, so you don't need a function...just make Z appropriately with your frequency data. `gx` and `gy` give `x` and `y` derivatives for every point in Z, which should be an `X` by `Y` matrix.

Comment: I already tried to do what you did in your example but gradient still give me 2 3-d vectors... Ab initio calculation gives me 8 frequencies for each point (it's a phonon dispersion relation) grid is a sampling of the brillouin zone. Don't know how to make Z appropriately, it should be already appropriate... Maybe gradient simply don't calculate gradient? I tryed with x**2+y**2, gradiend should be 2d vector: (2x,2y), but i still get 2 3-d vectors. How can i obtain the real gradient from such output?

Comment: I think your confusion comes from your expectation that gradient returns a vector of functions, when it cannot.  numpy doesn't do algebra like mathematica or maple.  You give `gradient` a matrix of your Z values and it computes step-wise the slope between each `X,X+1` and `Y,Y+1`, giving you for every point the rate of change of `x` and `y` at that point.  i.e. it approximates the evaluation of f(x,y) = `(2x,2y)`.

Comment: Why 3 components then? There are 2 directions so i would expect a 2 component vector...What should i do to get gradient? I didn't expect to get 2x,2y as output, but vectors with such components... in point (2,2) i would expect a vector (4,4), in point 1,3 i would expect (2,6) and so on. All i need is gradient module on each point, but i don't know how to work it out from numpy.gradient output... Have you got any suggestion?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. But my problem still unsolved. Following your example gx[0][2] should be 0 (dz/dz calculated on x0,y0) but it's not... I'm still confused about numpy.gradient's output. 3rd component  is a mistery to me

Comment: I'll update my question, i'll put a sample of my data, so you can see what's the problem here, i appreciate your efforts but your example does not resolve my problem. I did those checks before, maybe the problem is how i give data to gradient... i don't know. I'll put a little bit of data in my question.

Comment: I give up, i'm unable to put some formatted numbers in my question.

Comment: What are you talking about?  to make code snippets highlight the text and press ctrl+k, to make small inline snippets surround the text with "`" symbols.

Comment: I've update my question being more specific, tried to calculate that example in both ways (the one i've put in my question, and the one you suggest in your example) and results are different. This means that i need to change my input but the problem is that i don't know how to do that and which form i should give to my data.

Comment: How did you generate those plots? Very nice.

Comment: Thank you, it was just what I was looking for