# Exemplar-Based Inpainting - how to compute the normal to the contour and the isophate

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, numpy, calculus

I am using the Exemplar-Based algorithm by [Criminisi](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67276/criminisi_tip2004.pdf). In section 3 of his paper it describes the algorithm. The target region that needs to be inpainted is denoted as **Ω** (omega). The border or the contour of **Ω** where it meets the rest of the image (denoted as **Φ**(phi)), is **δΩ** (delta omega).

Now on page four of the paper, it states that **np**(n subscript p) is the normal to the contour of **δΩ**. and **▽Ip** (also includes orthogonal superscript) is the isophote at point **p**, which is the gradient turned 90 degrees.

My multivariable calculus is rusty, but how do we go about computing **np** and **▽Ip** with python libraries? Also isn't **np** different for each point **p** on **δΩ**?

Comment: That paper is amazing btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways of computing those variables, all depending in your numeric description of that boundary. `n_p` is the normal direction of the contour.

Generally, if your contour is described with an analytic equation, or if you can write an analytic equation that approximates the contour (e.g. a spline curve that fits 5 points (2 in each side of the point you want), you can derive that spline, compute the tangent line in the point you want using

[image]

Then, get a unit vector among that line and get the orthonormal vector to that one. All this is very easy to do (ask if you don't understand).

Then you have the **isophone**. It looks like its a vector orthonormal of the gradient with its modulus. Computing the *directional* gradient on an image is very very commonly used technique in image processing. You can get the X and Y derivatives of the image easily (hint: [numpy.gradient](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html), or [SO python gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901363/gradient-calculation-with-python)). Then, the total gradient of the image is described as:

[image]

So just create a vector with the x and y gradients (taken from numpy.gradient). Then get the orthogonal vector to that one.

**NOTE:** How to get an orthogonal vector in 2D

```
[v2x v2y] = [v1y, -v1x]
```

Comment: Okay, so I need to understand how I compute a contour line. Once i have figured out where the contour line pixels are, I need to define this curve as an equation, then derive it. I can't see how we compute for a tangent vector since the line has one variable. Can you give me example, I am not sure how to compute this.

Comment: You can compute the tangent vector of a curve if you know its derivative in  a point and a point! @JakeFund https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent

Comment: Okay, I see you have added more information on the tangent now. But it's still not clear to me. So function f is my spline curve. Given a point p1 at <x,y> and a point p2 at <a,f(a)>, I need to take the x value at p2 which is defined as a and plug it into the spline function (this should be the same as the y value at a), add that to the derivative of f at a, then multiply that by the difference from x to a. this should be equal to the original y value, so I  should subtract the y value and have the equation equal 0, then we have a single value for the tangent vector. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) chose your point `P`. 2) know your description of the curve that approximates the boundary (and also goes through `P`, of course) 3) derivate that curve 4) substitute point P on derivate. This should give a number. This is the slope , f'(a) in the equation. (a=x or a =y depends on how you described the curve. Irrelevant). 5)build line that goes through point P with the computed slope. 6)Get unit vector on that curve. 7) get orthonormal vector 8) `?????` 9)Profit! @JakeFund

Comment: 1. makes sense. 2. can you give me a nice hint to get the boundary, with images I am aware that boundaries will be a bit hard to define. 3. yes. 4. Let's say I define my curve on the x axis,  so a =x ,the derivative gives us the slope, okay. 5. Now we have to make a line equation, in code this would look something like: y + slope*(variable_X - x)... so that leads me to 6. where I am not sure how to get the unit vector but I believe this comes from my lack of understanding in step 5. 7. okay 8. I'll work on that soon. 9. Easier said than done.

Comment: 2) Given known points in the boundary use spline interpolation (google it, this is very very very common, you will probably find code). 5) If you have a line equation you can get 2 points on that line. `p2-p1/norm(p2-p1)` will give you a unit vector in that direction. @JakeFund

Comment: Okay so I tried looking up spline interpolation, and noticed that in python it seems difficult to get the coefficients from the formula. Therefore its going to be difficult to get the derivative of the spline function. Is there a good library for solving this?

Comment: Another thing I have noticed with splines that sort of contradicts what you stated is, usually splines don't go through points in the middle of the function　（I am looking at B-splines specifically. )How can we construct a spline that goes through point P? I am assuming we want P to be in the middle of the spline function.

Comment: @JakeFund You can make splines go through all poitns. If youhave questions about interpolation, open a new question please. It is a very very wide topic. Still, no need to use splines. you can even just linearly interpolate if you want. And the equation of the spline interpolation should be 3 lines of python, its not difficult to get coefficients if you know what it does! You dont need P in the middle of the spline, you want an analitic function of the boundary defined in P. P can be in a corner, as long as you can derivate the function and gives reasonable result

Comment: okay I asked another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381406/how-to-insure-spline-goes-through-points      I guess I don't need to coefficients since the scipy.interpolate library can find the derivative.

Comment: I will, once I figure out how to compute the normal of contour and the isophate.;) I am still not sure how to get normal vector, it looks like I need to take a course in numerical methods or something. What is the simplest way to get this unit vector?

Comment: I literally gave you the steps. Once you have the tangent line,  compute 2 any points on it. V=p2-p1/norm (p2-p1). This is high school maths.  Google it

Comment: Sorry, I understand that part. But the line itself seems difficult to get to, it seems I have to ensure that the point is on the curve while making a good curve as well that can be deferential.  You suggested to try linear interpolation, but will that allow me to get the derivative? So I am simply stuck on how to get this contour line.

Comment: Okay according to the paper on page 6. it say n_p can be computed by getting the positions of the "control" points of δΩ and filtering them with a bi-dimensional Gaussian filter. I guess I can take the result of the filter at the points before and after the point in question to get a line and then make it orthogonal. So I guess I'll do that. thanks for everything.