# How to insure spline goes through points

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, spline

I am trying to make a spline to compute the derivative of a [contour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331874/exemplar-based-inpainting-how-to-compute-the-normal-to-the-contour-and-the-iso) of a part of an image. The catch is that I don't seem to know how to make the spline go through a certain point. I am using the scipy.interpolate library with the UnivariateSpline method.

Comment: Please share your code as well

Comment: You have everything you need to know,  including step by step algorithms in Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation

Comment: If you are not using smoothing, the spline should go through each point used to construct it.

Comment: Ah really, good. I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkncKzflw8I and it appeared that the curve did not go through all the original points, only the first one and the last one. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `UnivariateSpline` use `s=0` to force interpolation: `UnivariateSpline(x, y, s=0)`. Or use `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`, which is exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your 'contour' can be arbitrary curve not necessarily a graph of a function. Then you need [splprep](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splprep.html#scipy.interpolate.splprep) which interpolate B-spline parametric curve, i.e. (x,y) = spline(t). UnivariateSpline is just for function splines, i.e. y = spline(x).